# How can I acqurie the JSON data from Kafka using SparkStreaming

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I use kafka monitor the alteration of LocalFile and SparkStreaming to analyse . But I can't extrct the data from the kafka because the format of data is JSON .

```
When I tap the command bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server master:9092,slave1:9092,slave2:9092  --topic kafka-streaming --from-beginning,
```

THE FORMAT OF DATA IS:

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "string",
    "optional": false
  },
  "payload": "{\"like_count\": 594, \"view_count\": 49613, \"user_name\": \"   w\", \"play_url\": \"http://upic/2019/04/08/12/BMjAxOTA0MDgxMjQ4MTlfMjA3ODc2NTY2XzEyMDQzOTQ0MTc4XzJfMw==_b_Bfa330c5ca9009708aaff0167516a412d.mp4?tag=1-1555248600-h-0-gjcfcmzmef-954d5652f100c12e\", \"description\": \"ţ ų   ඣ    9 9 9 9\", \"cover\": \"http://uhead/AB/2016/03/09/18/BMjAxNjAzMDkxODI1MzNfMjA3ODc2NTY2XzJfaGQ5OQ==.jpg\", \"video_id\": 5235997527237673952, \"comment_count\": 39, \"download_url\": \"http://2019/04/08/12/BMjAxOTA0MDgxMjQ4MTlfMjA3ODc2NTY2XzEyMDQzOTQ0MTc4XzJfMw==_b_Bfa330c5ca9009708aaff0167516a412d.mp4?tag=1-1555248600-h-1-zdpjkouqke-5862405191e4c1e4\", \"user_id\": 207876566, \"video_create_time\": \"2019-04-08 12:48:21\", \"user_sex\": \"F\"}"
}
```

The version of spark is 2.3.0 and the kafka version is 1.1.0. The version of spark-streaming-kafka is 0-10_2.11-2.3.0.

The JSON data in the column of PAYOAD is I want to deal with and analyse. How can I change the codes to acquire the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer` and `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` for consuming and sending data to kafka topic respectively.
This way you will get a String on consumption which can very easily be converted to JSON Object `using JSONParser`

Comment: Thank you! I solve the issue!  In the file  "connect-standalone.properties“”, "key.converter.schemas.enable" and "value.converter.schemas.enable" are "false", the data of "schema"  is wiped off.  Next I use the stream.map(record => record.replace()) for wiping off the "\" and “” in the  data of “PAYLOAD”